# Solve an equation using machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, regression, optimization, gan, structural-equation-modelling

Imagine we have the following equation: y=xz. We have y but not other ones. Note that y  is like a matrix and we could as many sample we want. It is the values obtained from sensors. This means it will be a m*n dataset where m represents number of samples and n represents the number of sensors. I am wondering whether we can use machine learning techniques (any method including GAN) to solve the equation and get at least one of the variables of x or z. Thanks.

Comment: It's ridiculously easy to find a solution: pick the identity matrix for x and y for z.

Comment: Could you please give a toy example. We just have and don't have x and z.

Answer (score 1):

Machine Learning is useful for problems which can't be solved (or not efficiently) with a deterministic method. The problem you propose is extremely simple since it doesn't even require any calculation, so there is no point using ML for it.

> Could you please give a toy example. We just have y and don't have x and z

Suppose

$y=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\
3 & 4\\
5 & 6\\
7 & 8\\
\end{bmatrix}$

An easy solution is to define $x$ and $z$ as follows:

$x=y=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\
3 & 4\\
5 & 6\\
7 & 8\\
\end{bmatrix}$ and  $z=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$